# Androidx: toolbar / actionbar icon color

Tags: android, kotlin

In my android app, I would like to change the color of the menu in the toolbar. This is how the toolbar is created

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
    return true
}
```

I have defined the color in `themes.xml` as following:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF3D7895</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#3E7997</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:iconTint">@color/white</item> <!-- This is the line that makes the icon color white -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

In the IDE, the menu icons are white as I declared, but when running it on an emulator (with API 30), the colors are black/gray (the default). This is also the case when deploying to my tablet (with API 29). So why are the colors overwritten when running the app?

Answer (score 0):

Try chaging the base theme `"Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"` to `"Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try 2 options:**

If you are using a vector drawable icon, then use `android:tint` in your icon

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    ... >
    <path
       ... />
</vector>
```

**The other option is:** in your `main_menu.xml`, use `app:iconTint` under your item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/..."
        app:iconTint="@color/white"
        android:icon="@drawable/..."
        android:title="..."/>
```

Comment: Yes, that is working in the preview but again, the problem is that it does not show up in a builded release on an emulator or physical device